# Force Event to Fire Internally

Tags: c#, events, composite-controls

In a composite control, how can I make an event fire internally?

Ie. I populate with some data, see that it's in the right condition (only one item) and then fire off my item selected event, calling the source page's OnItemSelected event.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some controls implement the ISupportInitialize interface, which has the BeginInit()/EndInit() methods. If you're doing batch updates to a control you can block events using BeginInit() and after you're done call EndInit(). Finally you set the selected item to fire the event or invoke the event directly.